# In Textarea some words become hyperlink automatically (summernote)

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

In the Textarea which was made by Summernote,

When I type some words with Colon(:) (For example, 'i:am' or 'you:are' something like that)

Then press Enter or Space bar, It becames to hyperlink automatically... a href tag created.

But only happens with the colon(:). Any Idea about this issue?

Thank you in advance.

### Code - JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#summernote").summernote({
        lang: 'ko-KR',
        height: 500,
        maxHeight: 500,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'video', 'table', 'hr']],
        ],
    });
  });
```

### Code - HTML

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

Comment: Add some code for better understanding.

Comment: One thing I noticed : After press Space or Enter key in above condition, <p> tag has <a> tag automatically.,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of summernote you are currently using. Because this issue has been fixed as mentioned in this post.

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/2935

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! I just updated to the new version, and no problem now :) I always have to keep up-to-date version